# Installing the tensor flow and its prerequisites

Tags: nvidia, cuda, nvidia-geforce

My computer has a GeForce 150MX installed and Ubuntu 18.04. I want to do a Tensor Flow training.

Questions: (1) Which version of CUDA should I install? (2) Which version of cuDNN should I install? (3) Which version of Tensor Flow should I install? (4) Should I install the graphics card driver before installing CUDA?

According to NVIDIA documentation, CUDA 10 is not compatible with GeForce MX150. But, I read in forums that this facility would be possible

Thank you all.

Comment: Maybe this tutorial helps: https://www.pytorials.com/how-to-install-tensorflow-gpu-with-cuda-10-0-for-python-on-ubuntu/

Comment: Thank you very much. It work for me: https://medium.com/@vitali.usau/install-cuda-10-0-cudnn-7-3-and-build-tensorflow-gpu-from-source-on-ubuntu-18-04-3daf720b83fe